# Formatting the legend in an SSRS chart with grouping

Tags: reporting-services, legend, ssrs-grouping

I've got a dataset of values that are based on keys and dates. For example, one date will have three different values with three different keys. So far as I know, the only way to get different series' based on keys is grouping. In addition, I want to display a single dotted horizontal line on the chart that is a static value in an expression.

Now the annoying bit is the legend. The chart itself looks fine, but the legend isn't smart enough to display different values for the different groups and creating a separate static series forces the legend to display two different groups, one for each series.

What I'm looking for is either:
A way to display the different key/value pairs in different series' without grouping

or:
A way to manually control which specific categories are displayed in the legend.

Let me know if I can provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you have two questions.

**How to add a static series to a chart**

Set to a static value in which where every category group has the same value for example -

GoalSeries.ValueField=Sum(Fields!Goal.Value)

```
Time     Value1       Goal
01/2010    2           5
02/2010    1.8         5
03/2010    3           5
04/2010    6           5
```

**How to hide a series from the legend.**

1. Select the series group or series value you want to hide the label for.
2. Right click and select properties
3. If it is a series value field select the "Legend" list view item and click the "Do not show on legend" check box.
4. If it is a series group field select the "General" list view items and set the Lable expression to a value to " ". The " " value will not show in series group legends.